# Aligning Image and Text in CSS Table

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, vertical-alignment

I have seen several CSS alignment tips, but none relating to a table.

My code for the table properties are as follows:

```
    table.pic {
    border-spacing: 1;
    }
    table.pic td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 4px solid #cccccc;
    }
    table.pic tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

    table.pic div {
        display:table-cell; 
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

This is my code for the first table row:

```
<table class="pic" style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img src="/sites/default/files/images/img.jpg" alt="" width="146" height="218" /></td>
<td>
<p>blahblah</p>
<p>poodle</p>
<p>noodle</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

No matter what change I try to make, the text still ends up on the cell to the right, but vertically it starts on the bottom line of the image. Anyone know what my issue is?

Comment: there is no `div` in the HTML sample you've given.

Comment: @Harsh where would I add div? I just tried putting it around the text block (<td><div>....</div></td>) and that didnt work.

Comment: <div><p>...</p>... </div> would wrap the text in a block element; with change to css to vertical align the div wrapper ... <td><div><p>...</p></div></td>

Answer (score 1):

On jsfiddle the text is not align with the bottom edge of the picture, it's vertically centered : http://jsfiddle.net/u3AW2/

Maybe you have overwrites somewhere.

The text is also vertically centered with  :

```
   table.pic td{
        display:table-cell; 
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Comment: I hate it when something changes the rules :(

Answer (score 0):

```
table.pic div {
        display:table-cell; 
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

aligns div elements, which are children of tables with a class of pic. I don't see the div in your html.

I assume you want

```
table.pic td {
            display:table-cell; 
            vertical-align:middle;
       }
```

to align all td elements of the table to vertical center.

**Updade:**

to attempt to override any theme rules you can get more selective

```
table.pic {
border-spacing: 1;
}
table.pic td {
padding: 5px;
border: 4px solid #cccccc;
}
table.pic tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

/* use more selectivity */
html body table.pic tr td {
    display:table-cell !important; 
    vertical-align:middle !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it still gives me the same results, text is aligned with the bottom edge of the picture

Comment: What browser? do you have an <!doctype html> in the html to put it in standards mode? With chrome it is centered.

Comment: im on chrome as well, but im using this through drupal 7

Comment: right click the element and select inspect element, look for any additional css rules that may be effecting the rules you are adding.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and found it was because I was using a CSS Reset. For some reason this was conflicting with my style sheet. I was specifically using the one on Meyerweb. Are you using this reset? If so, try changing the first rule as follows:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend, caption, tfoot, thead,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```